# admin link for managing likers of opengraph webpage disappeared

Tags: facebook, admin, facebook-opengraph

We have a pretty popular webpage about solar system http://www.solarsystemscope.com/ 

It has open graph tags, and a like button. and it has almost 90000 likers, to which we would like to post a news, that we are creating a new huge project about general education.

There WAS a admin page, where it was possible to access our fans. Now it disappeared, and we are not able to get it again.

We have checked the syntax and compared with the most common bugs, 
we have rechecked it also with the lintner

we have tried many other things.
And we have no idea what to try next.

Everything looks correct, but there is no link to the admin page.

The object for the page is

http://graph.facebook.com/10150134043072528

ANY idea or hint what to try next is appreciated !

Thanks a lot!

mayo

Answer (score 0):

I've come up against the same problem just today :)

You can figure out easily in three step:

1. Find open graph id for your webpage. Use https://graph.facebook.com for this.
2. Log In with the Facebook Username you use to admin your webpage
3. Follow http://www.facebook.com/{web page open graph id}

For example, entering into your browser (use firefox ;) :

https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.solarsystemscope.com/

you'll get:

```
{
   "id": "270906306253750",
   "name": "Solar System Scope",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276562_270906306253750_50107134_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.solarsystemscope.com/",
   "likes": 4132,
   "category": "Website",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.solarsystemscope.com/images/solarsystemscope_og_1.jpg",
   "description": "Watch and Play model of Solar System Planets and Constellations moving over the Night Sky.",
   "about": "Watch and Play model of Solar System Planets and Constellations moving over the Night Sky.",
   "can_post": true,
   "talking_about_count": 35
}
```

And after facebook login, follow this link https://www.facebook.com/270906306253750

Hope this helps